# Nginx - Serve Wordpress/app in one directory, if file not found try a different directory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm stumped on this. It seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to get it done.

I have an old site with thousands of old files.  These are hardly organized but need to be accessible.  I want to put these in /var/www/site/legacy/.

The current site runs wordpress.  I want wordpress to run in /var/www/site/wordpress/

I'd like the logic of things to go:

1. Go to www.site.com/
2. If ordinary Wordpress request (e.g., file in /wp-content/ or a templated page), deliver it by loading php reuqest in /var/www/site/wordpress/
3. If not a WP request, look for the file in /var/www/site/legacy/

It seems like I should be able to do something like this:

```
    root /var/www/site.com/wordpress;

    ....

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?args @legacy;
    }

    location @legacy {
            root /var/www/site/legacy;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
```

This *SHOULD* be easy but I've tried a dozen permutations of the above logic with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you have WordPress setup for pretty URLs, which might make this impossible to handle at the nginx level, so please post all relevant parts of your config, not just the bits you think the issue is with. Also,I think this is easier to handle the other way around. So first try legacy then new site.

Comment: I've actually taken that approach.  Legacy site first.  And I'm writing custom nginx rules to identify WordPress requests.  It seems to work.  I'll update with what I did once I've got it worked out a little more.